# Minimum break between rounds

Tags: rules, tournament, arbiters

I am an assistant arbiter in an open tournament which is happening over the weekend, with 1 round on Friday, and 2 rounds on Saturday and Sunday.

There were 5.5 hours between the two rounds on Saturday and Sunday, but some players finished their game just before the scheduled start of round 2.

The head arbiter gave them a 30-minute break before they had to start their second round, which seems appropriate, but I cannot find any rules or requirements from FIDE regarding this.

Searching for this topic, I only found rules regarding tie-breaks, with requirements for breaks between a match and the tie-break playoffs, and break between games in the tie-break.

Is there anything in the FIDE Laws of Chess, or anywhere else, or is it completely up to the tournament organizers how much time between rounds the players can get?

Comment: @Brian-Towers .... think you might be in the best position to answer this one.

Comment: Did the first round start on time? If it did, but some games still went on almost until the second round that was bad planning. If it did not, was there some outside cause that everyone just has to to accept? I doubt that there is any rule that could cover all circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the FIDE handbook either.

The [USCF](https://new.uschess.org/sites/default/files/media/documents/us-chess-rule-book-online-only-edition-chapters-1-2-10-11-9-1-20.pdf) has rule 17A:

> All games must be played in the tournament rooms at the times designated by the organizers unless the director specifies otherwise. For example, a player whose game ends late or is adjourned may be granted additional time to eat or rest (a half hour is common), or a first-round game may be scheduled for play before the start of the tournament.

It says the player "may" granted additional time, not that they "must" be granted this time, so it does seem to be up to the discretion of the organizers in the USCF.